# Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: php, html, arrays

Please am trying to input points for 8 teams,with just one form. I want to compare and get the highest score after the form has been submitted. I have created the form, but am having a little problem. Am getting "Undefined offset: 8" error. but the scores and name of the team shows perfectly. Here is my html code

```
<div class="container">
             <form method="post" action="../_libs/test.php">
            <?php
             foreach($teams as $arr)
             {
              ?>

                    <div class="row team_result">

                        <div class="col-md-8">

                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3"> <img class="img img-thumbnail" src="../_images/<?php echo $arr['Team_Logo']; ?>" width="50" height="50"> </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3"> <label> <?php echo $arr['Team_Name']; ?> </label> </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="points[]" placeholder="points">
                                </div>
                           <input type="text" name="Name[]" id="" value="<?php echo $arr['Team_Name'] ?>"
             style="display:none" >
                           </div>


                           </div>

                        </div>




                    </div>

              <?php  
             }

            ?>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-4"> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Post"> </div>
            </form>
            </div>
```

And the PHP code

```
<?php

 //echo json_encode($_POST);

 if(!empty($_POST['Name'])){
        $team=$_POST['Name'];
        $teams=count($team);
             for($i=0; $i <=  $teams; $i++)
                   {
                       echo $team[$i] .",". $_POST['points'][$i]."<br>";
                     // echo $teams;
                   }

 }


?>
```

Comment: use isset function before printing `if(isset($_POST['Name'])){ add you code here }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In for loop you need to use just `<`, not `<=`

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $teams; $i++)
```

While you use `<=`, you have 8 teams, but 9 iterations in your loop (for `$i` equal to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8). The last one is undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much @panther, It worked. Please how do i get the highest Points and the associated team name?

Comment: The best choice is to make that directly in DB. If you have just this code, set before for-loop var `$highest_points = 0; $highest_index = 0;`, than in for-loop `if ($_POST['points'][$i] > $highest_points) {$highest_index = $i; highest_points = $_POST['points'][$i];}`. After the whole loop you will have in `$highest_index` index of team with highet score. Than you can print that using echo `$_POST['Name'][$highest_index];`. I wrote that inline here, hope there are no typos. It should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should have the condition `$i < $teams`. the index of your array is always 0 indexed, but the count of an array always starts with 1. Your loop is going out of the array's bounds.

```
<?php
    //echo json_encode($_POST);

    if(!empty($_POST['Name'])){
        $team=$_POST['Name'];
        $teams=count($team);
        for($i=0; $i < $teams; $i++)
        {
            echo $team[$i] .",". $_POST['points'][$i]."<br>";
            // echo $teams;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jerodev. It worked,please how do i get the team with the Highest Points?